# Can I run deep learning frameworks (Theano or Tensorflow) with GPU acceleration on a Radeon Pro 450/455?

Tags: graphics-card, gpu, amd-radeon

I'm considering buying a new laptop. For my work, it would be ideal if I can run GPU-accelerated neural network frameworks on it, particularly Theano or Tensorflow.

Apple is offering a Macbook Pro with a "Radeon Pro 450" or a "Radeon Pro 460" option for the graphics card. Will I be able to run either Theano or Tensorflow on this GPU? If not, what about another framework?

I believe Theano and Tensorflow both use/require CUDA to work.

Comment: If Theano and Tensorflow both require CUDA, and since AMD GPU's do not support CUDA, that means you will be unable to run Theano and Tensorflow on any Macbook Pro with an AMD GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Macbook Pro with Radeon Pro 460 and tried to train a classifier using Caffe which has a OpenCL branch. Based on my experience, the speed of training the model on GPU was equally the same if you do it on CPU!
I also tried to do the same thing on a Mac with Nvidia 960 and guess what; it was 40 times faster! CUDA used pretty optimized structures for heavy matrix calculations which unfortunately is not available on AMD Graphic cards. So if your aim is to run GPU-based NNs, my personal recommendation would be to choose something with Nvidia Graphics.